# Can't access my hard drive with my windows files

Tags: hard-drive, usb-drive

I'm running Ubuntu 12.4 from a flash drive so that I can recover my windows files because my laptop is experiencing boot loop. How to locate my hard drive with my windows files?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 24.0 GB, 24015495168 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track,
2919 cylinders, total 46905264 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 =
512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O
size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
0x74f02dea

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    46903295    23450624   73  Unknown

Disk /dev/sdc: 15.7 GB, 15728640000 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track,
1912 cylinders, total 30720000 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 =
512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O
size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
0xfdc01076

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *          63    30719999    15359968+   c  W95 FAT32
(LBA) ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ^C ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B99TeByt30n2cFlVeFZDX1ZuUEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you opened the "windows explorer" known as Nautilus in Ubuntu?  On the left hand side of that listing near the middle it will have "Computer" listed as well as your windows hard drive.  What exactly it will be called will vary.  If you can't find it there then you will have to move onto the below answers.

Comment: here is an image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B99TeByt30n2cFlVeFZDX1ZuUEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you know the size of your windows hard drive?

Comment: You are right, it isn't in nautalis. So we will have to `mount` the drive prior to you being able to browse its files.

Comment: it is 500 GB and divided into two

Comment: Your HD is not showing up, can you add the output of 'cat /var/log/syslog` So we can see if perhaps there is an issue with the drive and if we can correct it.

Comment: i put the output in a doc file coz its too long..

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dNxzCfy5JkcSmaUZ9AcQovY_N7lnII2BQM8U3c370wI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Woah!!! How old is this hard drive? It is a `UDMA/133 ATA` type interface which was the FASTEST interface available until the SATA interface was released about a decade ago.  The issue is that your computer is unable to read the drive due to it failing.  I assume this is what caused your boot loop and why Ubuntu can not mount it... You will have to get a new drive, but as far as recovering data you may be out of luck. How old is it?  I will have to defer to someone who might have an idea of how to recover as all ideas I have will not work. I don't even know how to get access to it...

Comment: I dont want to leave you hopeless, I am searching! I also upvoted your question, I would add details about it failing and the link to your syslog, I could actually use a blockquote and actually put the log into your post

Comment: 3 years. it is a 7mm sata hitachi i guess.

Comment: Any feed-back on the upvoted answer???

Answer (score 2):

Here are the parts of the `syslog` that worry me and also how I came to my conclusion about the type of drive this is. This is not an answer just a way to show you and others what I think is wrong as the comments aren't long enough.

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/407007/what-do-these-disk-errors-in-syslog-mean) is something very similar to your situation.  You might try `ddrescue` [here](https://www.technibble.com/guide-using-ddrescue-recover-data/) is a guide.

```
Mar 18 23:52:37 ubuntu kernel: [  515.148659] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Mar 18 23:52:37 ubuntu kernel: [  515.148660] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Mar 18 23:52:37 ubuntu kernel: [  515.148661] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
Mar 18 23:52:37 ubuntu kernel: [  515.148668] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
Mar 18 23:52:37 ubuntu kernel: [  515.148671] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
Mar 18 23:52:37 ubuntu kernel: [  515.148678] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 1
Mar 18 23:52:37 ubuntu kernel: [  515.148680] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 2
Mar 18 23:52:37 ubuntu kernel: [  515.148690] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 3
Mar 18 23:52:37 ubuntu kernel: [  515.148702] ata1: EH complete
Mar 18 23:52:40 ubuntu kernel: [  518.747664] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x100000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Mar 18 23:52:40 ubuntu kernel: [  518.747678] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Mar 18 23:52:40 ubuntu kernel: [  518.747688] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Mar 18 23:52:40 ubuntu kernel: [  518.747701] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:a0:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq 4096 in
Mar 18 23:52:40 ubuntu kernel: [  518.747701]       res 51/40:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Mar 18 23:52:40 ubuntu kernel: [  518.747708] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Mar 18 23:52:40 ubuntu kernel: [  518.747712] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
Mar 18 23:52:40 ubuntu kernel: [  518.750284] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Mar 18 23:52:40 ubuntu kernel: [  518.750324] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
```

Comment: Next time use an internal AskUbuntu answer if you only provide links, but this is the best answer so far...

Comment: So linking to the `ddresuce` website is not acceptable?

Comment: [This](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) is the official Gnu ddrescue page...  :P Direct linking to Ubuntu.com, gnu.org, ... is allowed.  I would also have told @user3146700 to immediately start doing a `ddrescue` as his hard disk is *about to fail* and he needs to get all his data off ASAP. :/
For other sites, copy the relevant bits of info into your question and then mark the original site as your source.  ;-)

Comment: i also have a 24gb ssd and i can't find it

Comment: /dev/sdb is that 24 gig drive you were looking for. You just have to mount it

Comment: i can mount the 24gig. but i can't mount the sdb 500gig right?

Comment: So you were able to find the 24bg drive right? The other drive is falling do i would back up that data ASAP

Comment: i have no external storage. how should i back up. is there any other option.

Comment: You need to get a replacement drive that you can copy that data onto. Perhaps to another computer and then onto the new drive or directly onto the new drive would be easiest

Comment: i got an external drive. my problem now is that i cannot install DDRescue

Comment: Why not? You are booting into Ubuntu why cant you install it there?

Comment: i have no idea. btw im running the os using a flash drive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22082/discussion-between-dylan-and-user3146700).

Comment: I'am now using Hiren's but still I can't see my hard drive in disk management. But it is shown in device manager